# PostgreSQL How check that there is an intersection of sub array?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, intersection

I have `products` table with field `options`:
[image]

I want to find all products, which have at least one option, I needed. I request many options in one request to the DB and want to get all products, which have such option.

How can I do it?
I try this request:

```
SELECT * FROM "products" WHERE "options" @> '[["black", "M"],["blue", "7"]]';
```

And I get products, which have all this 2 options, with out products with 1 option.

I try this request:

```
SELECT * FROM "products" WHERE "options" && '[["black", "M"],["blue", "7"]]';
```

But I get error:

```
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Is it right way? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The data looks like a nested JSON array, so you can only use [JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) operators or functions.

To find rows with at least one option use an or condition with the `@>` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE options @> '[["black", "M"]'
   or options @> '[["blue", "7"]]'
```